# wordpress theme places footer above custom php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

[image]

Hello people,
I am creating a wordpress website with a theme and want to add custom php.
Everything is working except the theme keep placing its footer above the output of my own code.
I am not expecting u guys to fix it since u can't take look at it. but I really don't know where to look to fix this problem, it isn't the css.

As u can see I placed my code above the get_footer() function.
[image]

Is there a logic explanation for this?

I hope my story is clear enough, please ask questions if it isn't!

Comment: where did you include your custom.php

Comment: Look in your templates, header.php runs the header and footer.php runs the footer. I reckon, as @HappyCoding has mentioned your template is including the footer above your custom code, so check footer.php first for this call.

Comment: Showed the code in the question :)

Comment: inspect the source code and check you are not wrapping the table in a maincontainer.